# respondsToSelector: returns true for selector but setValue:forKey: then fails due to undefined key

Tags: ios, objective-c, respondstoselector

I am trying to utilise key-value coding to assign data to an instance of a small model class:

```
SEL selectorName = NSSelectorFromString(elementName);
if ([self.fixtureItem respondsToSelector:selectorName])
{
    [self.fixtureItem setValue:self.currentElementData forKey:elementName];
}
```

When `elementName` is 'description', `respondsToSelector:` returns true but `setValue:forKey:` then raises an `NSUnknownKeyException`:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this
>   class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'

Why does `respondsToSelector:` return true but `setValue:forKey:` then report that the key 'description' is actually undefined?

Comment: What is the type of fixtureItem ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description

Comment: fixtureItem is an instance of a simple model class: @interface FixtureItem : NSObject { }

Comment: Thanks, question edited to make it clear that I was aware of the NSObject base class 'description' instance method but didn't understand why setValue forKey would fail if respondsToSelector returned true.

Comment: @AndyBowskill Ever heard of readonly properties?

Comment: Are all of the down-votes really warranted? Seems a tad harsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you object does respond to the selector `@selector(description)` but does not respond to `@selector(setDescription:)`, which is what `setValue:forKey:` will ultimately call.

Answer (score 2):

Although your object indeed responds to selector `description` (because all `NSObject`-derived objects do), the description is not *settable*. The selector that you pass is for the getter `description`, not for a setter `setDescription:`.